# What is the least common factor in equation $\frac{5}{x+4}=4+\frac{3}{x-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I am attempting to solve for x $\frac{5}{x+4}=4+\frac{3}{x-2}$

I know that I need to find the least common denominator. In this case, since I cannot see a clear relationship among them all I think it's just the product of all 3 denominators:

$\frac{5}{x+4}=4+\frac{3}{x-2}$ = $\frac{5}{x+4}=\frac{4}{1}+\frac{3}{x-2}$

LCD: $(x+4)(1)(x-2)$ = $(x+4)(x-2)$

Is this the LCD?

Because I tried to use this in solving my equation but I arrived at a quadratic. I don't think that my textbook wants me to use quadratics in this section but I'm not sure. Here's how I arrived at that:

$\frac{5}{x+4}=\frac{4}{1}+\frac{3}{x-2}$

$(x+4)(x-2)\frac{5}{x+4}=(x+4)(x-2)\frac{4}{1}+(x+4)(x-2)\frac{3}{x-2}$

Then cancel out common factors:

$(x-2)5=(x+4)(x-2)(4)+(x+4)(3)$

$5x-10=(x+4)(x-2)(4)+3x+12$

And if I multiple out the middle term I'll get a polynomial, which is unexpected so I'm not sure I'm on the right path here... am I?

$5x-10=4x^2-4x-8+3x+12$

$5x-10=4x^2-x+4$

Comment: $(x+4)(x-2)(4)=(4x+16)(x-2)=4x^2+8x-32$

Comment: Rather than using lowest common denominator for problems like this, remember that you can multiply both sides of an equation by the same thing (just mind you don't divide by zero) and you will still have a valid equation. If you multiply through by the denominators you can simply clear the fractions. Then you have to be a little careful with any solution which makes one of the original denominators zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right path. Yes, you do get a quadratic. The quadratic that you should get is $10-6x-4x^2$ and its roots are $1$ and $-\frac52$.

Comment: When you say $10-6x-4x^2$ is this just for the middle term or after simplifying and equating to zero? I'm struggling to arrive at it.

Comment: After simplifying and equationg to zero.

Comment: Just for the part $(x+4)(x-2)(4)$ I get $(4x^2+24x+32)$ Is that incorrect?

Comment: Almost; it's $4x^2+8x-32$.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake in this step:

$$5x - 10 = (x+4)(x-2)(4) + 3x+12$$
$$5x-10 = (x^2+2x-8)(4) + 3x+12$$
$$5x-10 = 4x^2+\color{red}{8x}-\color{red}{32}+3x+12$$
$$5x-10 = 4x^2+11x-20$$
$$4x^2-6x-10 = 0$$

Alternatively, you can save a step by grouping under the $x+4$ term:
$$(x-2)(5)=(x+4)(x-2)(4)+(x+4)(3)$$
$$5x-10 = (x+4) \left(4(x-2) + 3 \right)$$

and you should get the same answer as before.

Comment: The quadratic is wrong in my answer. I'll edit once I see what what's wrong.